# upgrading Optaplanner to 8.25+ results in very slow performances

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner, timefold

After a while, I'm working again on a side-project which was using Optaplanner 8.20.

Since we now are in V8.42 (or 9.42 with quakus 3/java17) I tried to upgrade the app to the latest version (I would love to use quarkus 3) but I ran into multiple problems.

One of them is a huge drop in resulting performances.

The calculated scores  on a specific dataset used to be like that (optaplanner v8.24.1.Final):

```
2023-08-10 15:28:44,678 INFO  [io.fde.pla.bac.sol.ser.sch.SolverService] (executor-thread-0) running schedule problem febd43c7-54ae-4a9e-aea6-05e52ef8a175
2023-08-10 15:28:44,781 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolver] (pool-10-thread-1) Solving started: time spent (92), best score (-2544hard/-1116medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
2023-08-10 15:28:47,842 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-10-thread-1) Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (3153), best score (-1569hard/-682medium/-2314921soft), score calculation speed (25529/sec), step total (1116).
2023-08-10 15:28:47,843 INFO  [io ... thread-1)) -1569hard/-682medium/-2314921soft
2023-08-10 15:28:48,210 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1520hard/-698medium/-2266062soft
2023-08-10 15:28:50,369 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1201hard/-762medium/-2057769soft
2023-08-10 15:28:52,706 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -904hard/-808medium/-1914728soft
2023-08-10 15:28:55,170 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -685hard/-818medium/-2005894soft
2023-08-10 15:28:56,964 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -567hard/-827medium/-1899323soft
2023-08-10 15:28:58,717 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -485hard/-831medium/-2032438soft
2023-08-10 15:29:00,482 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -409hard/-833medium/-1994180soft
2023-08-10 15:29:02,220 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -350hard/-830medium/-1949107soft
2023-08-10 15:29:03,913 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -303hard/-831medium/-1908639soft
2023-08-10 15:29:05,689 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -263hard/-835medium/-1944460soft
2023-08-10 15:29:07,442 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -210hard/-836medium/-2005530soft
2023-08-10 15:29:09,693 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -186hard/-833medium/-1966828soft
2023-08-10 15:29:11,538 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -155hard/-833medium/-1953647soft
2023-08-10 15:29:13,601 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -139hard/-826medium/-2065612soft
2023-08-10 15:29:15,684 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -120hard/-829medium/-2059968soft
2023-08-10 15:29:17,603 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -106hard/-840medium/-1835454soft
2023-08-10 15:29:19,450 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -96hard/-823medium/-2125307soft
...
```

and after upgrading to 8.25 (or higher version, I tried with 8.42 for instance) I got that:

```
    2023-08-10 15:31:17,032 INFO  [io.fde.pla.bac.sol.ser.sch.SolverService] (executor-thread-0) running schedule problem a164dcde-393f-42e2-a2e3-c19b967b12f5
    2023-08-10 15:31:17,140 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolver] (pool-10-thread-1) Solving started: time spent (96), best score (-2544hard/-1116medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
    2023-08-10 15:31:20,343 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-10-thread-1) Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (3298), best score (-1569hard/-682medium/-2314921soft), score calculation speed (24405/sec), step total (1116).
    2023-08-10 15:31:20,343 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2314921soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:20,856 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2314603soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:23,609 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2307795soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:25,961 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2303770soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:28,604 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2301149soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:32,712 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2301060soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:35,349 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-682medium/-2296655soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:38,208 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-681medium/-2313953soft
    2023-08-10 15:31:51,813 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-680medium/-2351427soft
    2023-08-10 15:32:17,974 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-679medium/-2550884soft
    2023-08-10 15:32:20,601 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-679medium/-2545967soft
    2023-08-10 15:32:23,293 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-679medium/-2535134soft
    2023-08-10 15:32:45,319 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-678medium/-2607937soft
    2023-08-10 15:32:48,158 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-678medium/-2600937soft
    2023-08-10 15:32:50,932 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-678medium/-2578577soft
    2023-08-10 15:33:47,104 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-678medium/-2543732soft
    2023-08-10 15:33:53,129 INFO  [io ... thread-1) -1569hard/-678medium/-2542668soft
...
```

I can't find any changelog about the 8.25 optaplanner version.

Do you have any idea of where to start to look at?

I imagine it's related to the method used by the solver to try to optimize the problem but... I can't say why.

I was thinking to migrate to timefold 1.0, but I  need to fix this major performance drop first on my app

Comment: This is the full changelog between 8.24 and 8.25: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/compare/8.24.x...8.25.x

Nothing affecting performance stands out, unless you chose to use Constraint Streams Bavet (not default); in that case, there were a lot of changes, any of which could have caused this. However, there are regression tests on CS performance, so I find it unlikely something as massive as this would slip through the cracks. Without a reproducer, I won't be able to help.

Comment: thanks for you quick answer, 
Providing  a reproducer will require quite a bit of work to get something minimal.
I will do it, and maybe find the problem in the process... 
If I don't I will provide you the reproducer.

Answer (score 0):

From your before log:

```
2023-08-10 15:28:47,842 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-10-thread-1) Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: ..., score calculation speed (25529/sec), ...
```

From your after log:

```
2023-08-10 15:31:20,343 INFO  [org.opt.cor.imp.con.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase] (pool-10-thread-1) Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: ... score calculation speed (24405/sec) ...
```

Those 2 score calculation speeds are similar. Do you see a difference in the score calculation speed for "solving ended"?

Things to check:

- environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE) as your "solver started" log indicates is good. If either would be using FAST_ASSERT or FULL_ASSERT, that one would be artificially slow.
- log level should be info (or maybe debug). Not trace. For org.optaplanner, org.drools and org.kie.
- The fact that you have a bunch of System.out's in there could also
  slow down solving.

Things to do:

- Try optaplanner 8.38. I haven't benchmarked 8.42 yet and it's not unfathomable that a change in drools had a performance impact on optaplanner. Looking at [the commit logs](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/commits/main): even though the OptaPlanner code doesn't change any more, it does get updated to the latest version of Drools and optaplanner is released with that every month.
- Try Timefold 0.8 or 1.0. [It takes 2 minutes, run these instructions.](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/#upgrade-from-optaplanner-to-timefold) It doesn't use drools and the team has verified the quality of every release. Timefold is significantly faster than OptaPlanner out of the box.

Comment: thanks for you interest, I'm currently reworking the architecture of my app (I was getting stuck with a too simple architecture) and it was hard to isolate a potential problem.
Once it's done, I will try you suggestions and keep you informed here. 
Thanks

Comment: @minioim Did your investigation find something? Did you use the same Java version between both runs?
We're trying to investigate if you're [seeing the same issue as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77078059/slower-performance-after-upgrading-from-optaplanner-8-22-1-final-to-timefold-1-1).

Comment: That other StackOverflow is not related.

Comment: Hello @Geoffrey De Smet, I haven't yet found out the issue. 
But I used the same java version. I could check again if I missed something

But right now, I'm reworking entirely the project for 2 reasons: have a better architecture, and check on a regular bases if I have a drop in performances, and if so, why. So I can answer this question. 

Except... I'm very busy at work right now, so it is on a slow pace :/ I will keep you informed anyway