# Slower performance after upgrading from OptaPlanner 8.22.1 to Timefold 1.1.0 or OptaPlanner 8.37.0

Tags: performance, optaplanner, timefold

I have a course scheduling application based on OptaPlanner 8.22.1.Final.

After upgrading to Timefold 1.1.0, the execution time for the performance test cases increases about 100%. The application code is the same other than changes to point to the Timefold library. The JDK goes up from 11 to 17.

Here are some details about the tests.

Test case 1

Before

```
2023-09-10 13:02:17,390 INFO Solving started: time spent (5), best score (-730init/0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4), random (JDK with seed 0).
2023-09-10 13:02:17,902 INFO Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (517), best score (-40hard/-2265medium/0soft), score calculation speed (32158/sec), step total (365).
2023-09-10 13:03:31,283 INFO Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (73898), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (24932/sec), step total (28873).
2023-09-10 13:03:31,283 INFO Solving ended: time spent (73898), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (24979/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4).
```

After

```
2023-09-10 15:38:24,216 INFO Solving started: time spent (11), best score (-730init/0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4), random (JDK with seed 0).
2023-09-10 15:38:24,590 INFO Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (385), best score (-40hard/-2265medium/0soft), score calculation speed (87852/sec), step total (365).
2023-09-10 15:42:03,882 INFO Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (219677), best score (0hard/-10medium/0soft), score calculation speed (35648/sec), step total (31041).
2023-09-10 15:42:03,883 INFO Solving ended: time spent (219677), best score (0hard/-10medium/0soft), score calculation speed (35734/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4).
```

Test case 2:

Before

```
2023-09-10 13:03:32,508 INFO Solving started: time spent (16), best score (-3796init/0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4), random (JDK with seed 13).
2023-09-10 13:03:34,728 INFO Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (2236), best score (-10hard/-6460medium/0soft), score calculation speed (40084/sec), step total (1898).
2023-09-10 13:08:37,166 INFO Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (304674), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (13550/sec), step total (83120).
2023-09-10 13:08:37,167 INFO Solving ended: time spent (304675), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (13742/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4).
```

After

```
2023-09-10 15:42:04,616 INFO Solving started: time spent (32), best score (-3796init/0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4), random (JDK with seed 13).
2023-09-10 15:42:07,385 INFO Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (2801), best score (-10hard/-6460medium/0soft), score calculation speed (64265/sec), step total (1898).
2023-09-10 15:52:28,340 INFO Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (623756), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (12726/sec), step total (82742).
2023-09-10 15:52:28,341 INFO Solving ended: time spent (623757), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (12954/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (4).
```

I also tried OptaPlanner 8.37.0.Final and a few other version after the introduction of Bavet. They all caused performance degradation.

What changes do I need to make to make the application run faster? I was expect the application to run slightly faster.

Comment: Would you mind doing the runs on the same JDK version? We have reason to believe it could be involved and love to exclude that.

Comment: You can use Timefold 0.8.40 with JDK 11 as a comparison. Or the original code on JDK 17.

Comment: I will run more tests

Answer (score 1):

We believe the original code might be **overfitting** and **the change in JDK version exposed that**. If that's true, the change in OptaPlanner/Timefold version isn't relevant. In fact, the upgrade will probably improve your production quality (= paradox).

A benchmark on the same JDK version should (dis)prove that.

**Motivation**

1. The testcases use a different random seed according to the log:

- Testcase 1 (before+after): `Solving started: ... random (... seed 0)`
- Testcase 2 (before+after): `Solving started: ... random (... seed 13)`

That is very unusual. It's a sign of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). Overfitting gives better results during testing, but equal or worse results in production.
I suspect optaplanner-benchmarker has been (mis)used to find the "best random seed" for each dataset. That makes it vulnerable to any changes in the random implementation.

2. JDK 17 [changed the random implementation](https://openjdk.org/jeps/356).
3. The time spent more than doubled, but the score calculation speed and LS steps remained the same. That means the number of moves per step more than doubled. It just generated more unlucky moves.

Comment: Here are the steps I have taken.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Here were the steps I took.
1. Upgraded JDK from 11 to 17. That resulted score calculation speed from ~15% percent to  80% faster. 
2. Upgraded from OptaPlanner 8.22.1.Final to Timefold 1.1.0. The score calculation speed was about the same as step 1. The number of steps were about the same. 

As you mentioned, it was the number of moves per step. What should I do to keep down the number of steps.

Comment: I meant to ask how to keep down the number of moves per step.

Comment: Regarding overfitting, I can think of a few things. AcceptedCountLimit and StepCountingHillClimbingSize. Should I tweak them?

Comment: What we see is not directly related to number of steps, or any advanced configuration of the algorithm. We believe we are seeing that, for each solution, your program chooses a very specific random seed that has been benchmarked at some point in the past to work best for that data set. Unfortunately, the RNG changed in the JDK and those hand-crafted random seeds no longer work well. The solution is to either re-benchmark every data set to find the new "best" random seeds, or stop this practice altogether. We think this is not a solver performance regression.

Comment: Don't tweak accepted count etc. Take out your random seeds. Benchmark using the same JDK versions. Then bisect benchmark the versions from OptaPlanner 8.22 to 8.38 to Timefold 0.8 to Timefold 1.2. If you can tell us which exact version introduced the suspected result quality regression, we can investigate what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the test logs, it seems to me that you're comparing apples to oranges. Specifically:

Test case 1:

- "before" ran for ~ 1 minute 15 seconds
- "after" ran for ~ 3 minutes 30 seconds.
- the result "after" was **significantly faster** than "before". (~ +45 %)

Test case 2:

- "before" ran for ~ 5 minutes.
- "after" ran for ~ 10 minutes.
- the result "after" was only worse by about 6 %, which can be easily explained by natural variance in JVM performance from one run to another.

Considering that the input conditions (specifically solving time or target score) are not the same and that this is not a scientific benchmark, I would be cautious in drawing any conclusions from it.

Here are a few guidelines to improve the reliability of your benchmarks:

- Set a shared termination condition. If you're measuring performance, time-based terminations aren't ideal. Maybe a score-based or a step count-based termination.
- Run each experiment multiple times, average the results. 10 iterations each should suffice.
- Try to eliminate variables. If you say you've reproduced this with OptaPlanner 8, don't benchmark Timefold (yet). Instead, try to reproduce it without a switch to JDK 17. That way, we'll know if it's JDK-related or not.

As a final note, it is not the first time that I'm hearing that *something* happened some time after OptaPlanner 8.22 which caused it to go significantly slower in some cases. Unfortunately, no one has yet provided code that would show the slowdown. You can be the first.

Comment: Thanks. I use step count hill climbing. The termination conditions include: UnimprovedStepCountLimit, SecondsSpentLimit, UnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit. I will try the other suggeestion.